# Combine two queries into one and paginate together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, will-paginate

I have two scoped queries that I need to paginate together. Individually, they look like this:

```
a = @person.company.tasks.open.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
b = @person.tasks.private.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
@tasks = (a + b).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

#### What works

I do successfully get a merge when I do `@tasks = (a + b)` and the results paginate.

#### What doesn't

With the variables added together, the sorting doesn't work any more.

Comment: when you do `(a + b).paginate`, is `a = @person.company.tasks.open.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)` and `b = @person.tasks.private.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)`?

Comment: @rubyprince - yes, but minus the pagination (I'm trying to do that part together).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one query, getting the tasks based on the id's returned by the 2 queries:

```
company_task_ids = @person.company.tasks.open.pluck(:id)
private_task_ids = @person.tasks.private.pluck(:id)
@tasks = Task.where(:id => (company_task_ids + private_task_ids)).paginate :page => params[:page], :order => (sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

This can be optimised a bit, but this should get you on your way

Comment: Hi Bert, thanks for this. It does work but you're right it's a little slow - where should I look if I want to speed this up a bit?

Comment: You could get the pure SQL statements via .to_sql after the select statement. Then via ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(SQL) you should have the ids a lot faster...

Comment: what about `.pluck(:id)` instead of `.select('id').collect(&:id)`?